# Time Difference in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to translate following code to PowerShell 2.0...without success so far.

```
$startTime = (Get-Date)
<my_script_is_running>
$endTime = (Get-Date)
$ElapsedTime = 'Duration: {0:hh} h {0:mm} min {0:ss} sec' -f ($endTime-$startTime)
Write-Host "$ElapsedTime"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Describe "success" and "without success" - what happens in PowerShell 2.0? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: No errors. Formatting issues.

Comment: Show us the results then! What does it look like when it works vs when it doesnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that PowerShell v2 is not recognizing the standard date/time formats for `TimeSpan`. (I put `Start-Sleep -Seconds 2` to have some timediff).

PowerShell 2 output:

```
Duration: 00:00:02.0001144 h 00:00:02.0001144 min 00:00:02.0001144 sec
```

PowerShell 5 output:

```
Duration: 00 h 00 min 02 sec
```

You can format "manually" specifing the TimeSpan properties:

```
$ElapsedTime = ('Duration: {0} h {1} min {2} sec' -f $elapsed.Hours, $elapsed.Minutes, $elapsed.Seconds)
```

Works in both versions.